# Concurrent File reads / writes in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, file-io, concurrency

I have a large files where I store `Binary` data. There are multiple threads reading and writing these files, an my current design synchronizes them using a single `Lock`. This way, I have only one `Handle` in `ReadWriteMode` open for a file, and all threads fight for that single lock when they feel like doing some I/O.

I'd like to improve upon this by allowing multiple readers to work concurrently. What I tried was using a [`RWLock`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/concurrent-extra-0.7.0.6/docs/Control-Concurrent-ReadWriteLock.html) and having multiple Handles open. The `RWLock` would ensure that only one thread modifies the file, while many threads (as many as I have handles open, a compile-time constant) are allowed to read concurrently. When trying to run this, I was hit by the fact that the runtime [allows only one](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#g:8) `Handle` in `ReadWriteMode` to exist for a file at any time.

How can I resolve this situation? I assume obtaining / releasing a `Handle` is an expensive operation, so just opening the file in the appropriate mode after acquiring the `RWLock` is not really an option. Or maybe there is a package offering an API similar to Java `FileChannel`'s [read](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#read(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20long)) and [write](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#write(java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20long)) methods?

PS: I'd like to support 32bit architectures, so memory-mapped IO is not possible for files > 4GiB, right?

Comment: Have you tried using any parallel I/O library for reading writing files? There are a couple of them, HDF5, PNetCDF, SIONlib... all of them support concurrent reading/writing to files in parallel in both shared and distributed memory systems and they all scale pretty good to up to O(10^4) cores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is that you don't want to use stateful `Handle`s (where the state is the current location in file)?  In that case, you need `pread` and `pwrite`, I guess.

`man pread`

For Haskell binding: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unix-bytestring-0.3.7.2/docs/System-Posix-IO-ByteString.html

For a usage example, you can look here: https://github.com/errge/PrefetchFS/blob/master/PrefetchHandle.hs

Comment: This looks like a perfect match, I'll try it shortly.

Answer (score 2):

You should build an type around the file handle and a mutex lock. Here's a simple implementation that I think would work for your purposes.

```
module SharedHandle (SharedHandle, newSharedHandle, withSharedHandle) where

import Control.Concurrent.MVar
import System.IO              

data SharedHandle = SharedHandle Handle (MVar ())

newSharedHandle :: IO Handle -> IO SharedHandle
newSharedHandle makeHandle = do
    handle <- makeHandle
    lock <- newMVar()
    return $ SharedHandle handle lock

withSharedHandle :: SharedHandle -> (Handle -> IO a) -> IO a
withSharedHandle (SharedHandle handle lock) operation = do
    () <- takeMVar lock
    val <- operation handle
    putMVar lock ()
    return val
```

What's doing on here is I've created a new datatype which is, at it's essence, just a file handle. The only difference is that it also comes with its own individual mutex lock implemented with an MVar. I have provided two functions for operating on this new type. newSharedHandle takes a operation that would create a normal handle and created a shared handle with a fresh lock. withSharedHandle takes an operation for operating on handles, locks the shared handle, performs the operation, and then unlocks the handle. Notice that the constructor or accessors are not provided from the module so we can be assured no process ever forgets to free the lock and we never get deadlocks on one particular access.

Replacing all file handles in your program with this new type could solve your problem.

Comment: Isn't this pretty much what I'm already doing? I don't see how this would allow multiple readers to operate concurrently, as they all content for the single `MVar` (which is more or less used as a `Lock` in this code). Also, it's not exception-safe. ;-)

Comment: I thought you wanted to have many files written to at once but individually lock them so as to not lock the whole set together. If you want to actually write to the same file both at the same time, isn't it just fine to have unchecked race conditions? Posix already allows you to have multiple processes append to a file without any locking. In short, what's the problem with your program just not locking anything and letting the faster process win the race and be the first to write?

Comment: Oh, maybe I should have stated that explicitely: My files are fixed size and I write to / read from random offsets within a file. My problem is the race between seeking to the correct offset and actually doing the I/O, when multiple threads access a single file. I only have two files, but dozens of readers/writers.

Comment: Ah. That is very different from what I understood. Well... what operations do you have? Can you ever add or remove lines? You might need to have a lock per line and also a special lock when you are going to add lines so that the per line lock is not thrown off. You know what? This is starting to sound an awful lot like a database. Do you need to do this in 4GB files? What's the higher-level task?

Comment: It's basically a huge hash table, containing lots of fixed-size elements. I have two files, one for elements of ~2kiB and one for ~32kiB elements. The files are very simple in their structure (just the elements packed tightly together), but really large (1TiB is my largest currently). My operations are only "lookup" and "put", each requiring to position the file offset and then reading/writing a `ByteString` of the known size.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect application for memcached or something based on it, like perhaps Redis. Have you looked into either of those?

Comment: I'd like to have this run on an Raspberry Pi, so I'll probably have to stay a bit more low level. :-)